# Inferring incidence from prevalence

Tags: hypothesis-testing, epidemiology, medicine

I have a data set of patients with a risk factor for disease "A", which can be of grade 1, 2 or 3. The grade is determined by a lab value, i.e. `Healthy <20`, `Sick (1) 20-30`, `Sick (2) 30-40`, `Sick (3) >40`.

I have data that looks like so:

```
No. Age1  Lab1 Age2 Lab2
1   21    21   30    30
2   23    28   34    37
3   22    26   27    29
...
```

`Age1` is the first time `Lab1` was measured in this individual. `Age2` is the second time, `Lab2`, this lab was measured *in the same individual*.

1. I'm struggling with how to statistically describe the change in my own population. Should I average `age 1` (`age1_mean`) and `lab1` (`lab1_mean`), average `age2` (`age2_mean`) and `lab2` (`lab2_mean`) and discuss the *average mean difference in lab values* (`lab2_mean - lab1_mean` $\pm$ **95% CI**) over *x* amount of years (`age2_mean - age1_mean` $\pm$ **95% CI**)?
2. To determine the significance of the change in `lab2` from `lab1` in my population, I would use a *paired T-test*, correct? Because this is essentially just a "before and after" study of the same cohort.
3. How can I determine incidence of this disease such to say the incidence of "healthy to grade 1" is **x%** $\pm$ **95% CI** per year, "grade 1 to grade 2" is **y%** $\pm$ **95% CI** per year, etc.?

Lastly, I have access to CDC data that demonstrates:

```
Healthy
Age    %   SE 
20-34  37.6 1.8
35-44  20.5 1.6
45-54  18.7 1.6
55-64  22.7 1.4
65-74  22.2 2.2

Grade 1
Age    %   SE 
20-34  60.4 1.8
35-44  79.3 1.6
45-54  80.8 1.7
55-64  76.7 1.4
65-74  76.1 2.3

...
```

And so forth to include tables for grade 2 and grade 3.

4. The CDC data is actually just prevalence since its a snap shot in time, but can I infer incidence in any way? I'm assuming you can but it is subject to many assumptions. If so, how would I conduct a hypothesis test to demonstrate that the incidence I determined in **question 3** is significantly higher or lower than the what the CDC incidence suggests?

Comment: Given all your demands, have you thought about using regression?

Comment: I am unfortunately too inexperienced with advanced statistics to know whether or not that will answer my question, let alone how to perform it. If you had the time and energy to spare discussing how this may benefit me and pointing me in the right direction (especially in regard to conducting it in `R`, I would be ever grateful.